# USB Drive does not showing on Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: 22.04, usb-drive

My usb-drive does not showing on my Ubuntu folder and on my windows folder.

Here is the result of `list disk` on Windows:

```
DISKPART> list disk

  Disk ###  Status         Size     Free     Dyn  Gpt
  --------  -------------  -------  -------  ---  ---
  Disk 0    Online          476 GB      0 B        *
* Disk 1    No Media           0 B      0 B
```

And this the Disk app appreance on Ubuntu:
[image]

But it can't format
[image]

When I check the `lsblk`

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE     FSVER        LABEL                  UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0  squashfs   4.0                                                                              0   100% /rofs
loop1  squashfs   4.0                                                                              0   100% /snap/bare/5
loop2  squashfs   4.0                                                                              0   100% /snap/core20/1405
loop3  squashfs   4.0                                                                              0   100% /snap/firefox/1232
loop4  squashfs   4.0                                                                              0   100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/99
loop5  squashfs   4.0                                                                              0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop6  squashfs   4.0                                                                              0   100% /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/10
loop7  squashfs   4.0                                                                              0   100% /snap/snap-store/575
loop8  squashfs   4.0                                                                              0   100% /snap/snapd/15177
sda                                                                                                         
├─sda1 vfat       FAT32                               472C-E568                                             
└─sda2 LVM2_membe LVM2 001                            E4D1Ff-vICr-wd3r-Vhjl-m4c8-tHRQ-U6GXqV                
  ├─skx--vol-root
  │    ext4       1.0                                 dbc242db-35a2-4f7d-8706-8bf10e3fc28e                  
  ├─skx--vol-home
  │    ext4       1.0                                 2fdd9573-9b2e-41d4-8584-1acee9d88e99                  
  ├─skx--vol-var
  │    ext4       1.0                                 46328e77-dd87-408c-9308-4541451c7a33                  
  ├─skx--vol-tmp
  │    ext4       1.0                                 537d6f80-04a2-41cd-af15-2541132c1947                  
  └─skx--vol-swap
       swap       1                                   2bf9600e-39c4-4569-824f-e8986601d6f2                  
sdc                                                                                                         
sr0
```

Then it showing result like this when I format the **sdc** which is that my usb-drive.

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdc
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdc: No medium found
```

I try to check the log  `/var/log/syslog` and try to plug in and out my drive, and here is the log:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# tail -f /var/log/syslog 
Jul 24 10:24:42 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Jul 24 10:24:42 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Jul 24 10:24:43 ubuntu kernel: [  978.028993] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Mass-Storage     1.11 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jul 24 10:24:43 ubuntu kernel: [  978.029836] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Jul 24 10:24:49 ubuntu kernel: [  984.086727] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Media removed, stopped polling
Jul 24 10:24:54 ubuntu kernel: [  989.623780] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jul 24 10:25:16 ubuntu systemd-udevd[9418]: sdc: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdc' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 24 10:25:28 ubuntu gnome-disks[6038]: g_dbus_interface_get_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_INTERFACE (interface_)' failed
Jul 24 10:25:28 ubuntu gnome-disks[6038]: g_dbus_interface_get_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_INTERFACE (interface_)' failed
Jul 24 10:26:18 ubuntu rtkit-daemon[2077]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.



Jul 24 10:27:29 ubuntu kernel: [ 1144.805834] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
Jul 24 10:27:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 1147.409097] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci

Jul 24 10:27:32 ubuntu kernel: [ 1147.709074] usb 1-1.2: device descriptor read/64, error -71
Jul 24 10:27:33 ubuntu kernel: [ 1147.929632] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1908, idProduct=0226, bcdDevice= 1.11
Jul 24 10:27:33 ubuntu kernel: [ 1147.929647] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
Jul 24 10:27:33 ubuntu kernel: [ 1147.930301] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul 24 10:27:33 ubuntu kernel: [ 1147.930547] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-1.2:1.0
Jul 24 10:26:18 ubuntu rtkit-daemon[2077]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jul 24 10:27:33 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Jul 24 10:27:33 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Jul 24 10:27:33 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Jul 24 10:27:33 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Jul 24 10:27:34 ubuntu kernel: [ 1148.941646] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Mass-Storage     1.11 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jul 24 10:27:34 ubuntu kernel: [ 1148.942345] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Jul 24 10:27:40 ubuntu kernel: [ 1154.999336] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Media removed, stopped polling
Jul 24 10:27:45 ubuntu kernel: [ 1160.536499] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk

Jul 24 10:28:07 ubuntu systemd-udevd[9508]: sdc: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sdc' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 24 10:28:11 ubuntu rtkit-daemon[2077]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jul 24 10:28:11 ubuntu rtkit-daemon[2077]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jul 24 10:28:18 ubuntu gnome-disks[6038]: g_dbus_interface_get_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_INTERFACE (interface_)' failed
Jul 24 10:28:18 ubuntu gnome-disks[6038]: g_dbus_interface_get_object: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_INTERFACE (interface_)' failed
Jul 24 10:28:41 ubuntu rtkit-daemon[2077]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.


    
Jul 24 10:28:41 ubuntu rtkit-daemon[2077]: Supervising 7 threads of 4 processes of 1 users.
Jul 24 10:30:01 ubuntu CRON[9603]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
```

The issue become happen after I don't eject my usb-drive before I remove/unplug usb-drive out.

So what happen in my drive?, is that already broken? or any other way to fix that?

Comment: Unplug the drive. Watch `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you reconnect it. Also use `sudo lsblk -f` to see if there are partitions on it.

Comment: Hi @waltinator, thank you for the response, I have bring the usb drive to the computer repair shop, they have tested the usb drive, but the problem still same. then at the end I bought a new usb drive. But thank you for all that have help me by answer my question here.